# How to read a comma position from an Array C#

Tags: c#

Hi I'm Trying o make an atom simulation game where I can read my data from a txt file and use the data for the simulation/game. I have read the file but I am having trouble finding the commaposition from the string array. The txt file looks like this: 1,H,Hydrogen,1,1+
3,Li,Lithium,7,1+

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string commapostition;

    string[] list = new string[44];

    StreamReader rFile = new StreamReader(@"JUNK1.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++)
    {
        list[i] = rFile.ReadLine();
    }
    rFile.Close();

    for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++)
    {
        commapostition = list[i].IndexOf(',');
    }

}
```

Comment: You can read the composition of each line by using `list[i].Split(',');`. It gives you an array of all the parts of a string in between the commas.

Comment: Also, if that is really the extent of your txt file, then `list` is going to have the file contents at index 0 followed by 43 `null`s. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but how would I be be ale to use that later on to read other values. Like i mean i want to find out the comma position so I can read other values like the numbers or Name for example `Symbol = Substring.list(commaposition + 1);`

Comment: Your txt file example didn't say anything about Name, just various different symbols. If there is more to the file, can you post it please?

Comment: 1,H,Hydrogen,1,1+
3,Li,Lithium,7,1+
11,Na,Sodium,23,1+
19,K,Potassium,39,1+
37,Rb,Rubidium,85,1+
55,Cs,Casesium,133,1+
87,Fr,Francium,223,1+
4,Be,Beryllium,9,2+
12,Mg,Magnesium,24,2+
20,Ca,Calcium,40,2+

Comment: That is how the file looks

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Do you really think your post in the comments are readable?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Is it all on one line like that?

Comment: the order is atomic number, symbol, name, mass, charge. And i want to read those values into a seperate strings that can be later used

Comment: @Abion47 No its not

Comment: @AbdullahKhan what is so hard to understand.. post the file content **exactly** as it is....

Comment: @AbdullahKhan :))))))))) funny....

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Either post the contents of the file in your question or put it in a pastebin (or similar). If we can't see **exactly** how the file appears then our solutions likely wouldn't work.

Comment: 1,H,Hydrogen,1,1+

Comment: that is how one line looks. there are others after

Comment: Then I stand with what I said. Full solution to come in an answer.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G5cQQdqm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each line of your file looks like what you posted:

```
1,H,Hydrogen,1,1+
```

And the order `Atomic #, Symbol, Name, Mass, Charge` is constant, you can do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = @"JUNK1.txt";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] entries = lines[i].Split(',');

        string atomicNumber = entries[0];
        string symbol = entries[1];
        string name = entries[2];
        string mass = entries[3];
        string charge = entries[4];

        // Do stuff with these values...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a text file `JUNK1.txt` with the lines:

```
1,H,Hydrogen,1,1+
3,Li,Lithium,7,1+
```

You can read this line as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Path to the file you want to read in
    var filePath = "path/to/JUNK1.txt";

    // This will give you back an array of strings for each line of the file
    var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

    // Loop through each line in the file
    foreach (var line in fileLines)
    {
        // This will give you an array of all the values that were separated by a comma
        var valuesSeparatedByCommas = line.Split(',');

        // Do whatever with the array valuesSeparatedByCommas
    }
}
```

After the above code executes for the first line, the variable `valuesSeparatedByCommas` array will look like the following:

```
  0   1      2       3    4
+---+---+----------+---+----+
| 1 | H | Hydrogen | 1 | 1+ | 
+---+---+----------+---+-----
```

And now you can access each part of the line based on it's index:

```
// valueAtPosition0 will be '1'
var valueAtPosition0 = valuesSeparatedByCommas[0];

// valueAtPosition1 will be 'H'
var valueAtPosition1 = valuesSeparatedByCommas[1];
```